# change color of jlabel when we move mouse pointer

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a question about jlabel. I want to change colour of jlabel when we move mouse pointer over it. Also change mouse cursor like figure pointer. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), describe which actions you have already taken to solve the problem and what exactly does not work yet.

Comment: Please search first before asking, and then show the specific results from your search with your question. Else you're just asking folks to regurgitate that which has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to accomplish that:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setCursor(CURSOR);
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        label.setForeground(COLOR1);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        label.setForeground(COLOR2);
    }
});
```

Note that like this the cursor will only be different when inside that label so you may want to do frame.setCursor instead to have that change affect the whole window.

Comment: Inheriting from [MouseAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) instead of implementing MouseListener saves you from implementing all those emtpy unused methods.